# CSS Problems - works in Firefox, not in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, css, firefox, layout

I've a problem with the lay-out of my site; I've searched all over, but can't find the answer. I've fiddled around as well with what I can without screwing up lay-out for both FF and IE..
Basicly, I want 2 tables, each in seperate divs (or just divided from each other) and have them with a height of about 30 - 40% and have scrollbars whenever it is needed.

Code for my CSS-file:

2 tables, `#Manifestaties` & `#detail_info`, placed in each a seperate div, within one div, `#resultlist`:

```
#resultlist {
height: 80%;
left: 8%;
position: absolute;
top: 20%;
width: 35%;
}

#Manifestaties {
display: block;
height: 30%;
overflow-y: auto;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
}

#detail_info {
display: block;
height: 30%;
overflow-y: auto;
position: absolute;
top: 35%;
width: 100%;
}
```

Link to the website:
http://onderzoek.knokke-heist.be/extern/ww/manifest.html

Thanks for any help!

*EDIT*
Fixed it myself, IE interprets height & width as min-height, min-width. So changed code to:
...
min-height: 35%;
height: auto;

and with a conditional css in my html that chooses a different css-file when I'm using IE 9 or greater.

Comment: Which versions of the browsers are giving you issues?

Comment: I'm using IE-9, haven't tried with 10 (can't install on laptop here).

Comment: Your fixes seem to work in IE10 :).

Comment: @Jellyfish if this question is already solved either post your colution as an answer or delete your question.

Comment: Ah, k, sorry, didn't know how...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem: 
IE interprets height & width as min-height, min-width.

Answer: 
changed code to: max-height: 35%; height: auto;
from height: 35%;